# Cannot keep the video-frame-window from closing

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-capture

Below is a simple program that opens a video file, reads the contents, converts them to a log-polar format, and writes out the log-polar image to a new video file.

I have placed my input video in the `Projects` / `Properties` / `Debugging Arguments` as `argv[1]` but I do not know where the output ( i.e. `argv[2]` ) will be placed when produced.

Also, despite using `system( "pause" );` at the very end, the window closes down immediately, so I cannot see the message there.

So, my questions are: **(1)** Where is `argv[2]` placed once formed? **(2)** Why the window does not stay open, waiting for a keystroke?

Thanks in advance,

```
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
 CvCapture* capture = 0;

 capture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );

 if( !capture ) return -1;

 IplImage* bgr_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

 double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS );

 CvSize size = cvSize( (int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH ), (int)cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT ) );

 CvVideoWriter* writer = cvCreateVideoWriter( argv[2], CV_FOURCC( 'M', 'J', 'P', 'G' ), fps, size );

 IplImage* logpolar_frame = cvCreateImage( size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 ); 


 while( ( bgr_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ) ) != NULL )
 {
  cvLogPolar( bgr_frame, logpolar_frame, cvPoint2D32f( bgr_frame->width/2, bgr_frame->height/2 ), 40, CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS );      
  cvWriteFrame( writer, logpolar_frame );
 }

 cvReleaseVideoWriter( &writer );   
 cvReleaseImage( &logpolar_frame );
 cvReleaseCapture( &capture );  

 system( "pause" );
}
```

Comment: Just try with showimage() and waitkey() and It is always recommended to use C++ instead of outdated C, See [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17546/opencv-will-drop-c-api-support-soon/)

Comment: Thanks, I will, but I am still confused: what should I show? argv[2]?  Is that the file name I should use?

Comment: Show your image in  a window.

Comment: I added cvNamedWindow( "Display Window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); after IplImage* bgr_frame = cvQueryFrame( capture ); and also added cvShowImage( "Display Window", capture ); plus char c = cvWaitKey(33); in the WHILE loop and then at the end I added cvDestroyWindow( "Display Window" ); but I still do not get anything...

Comment: Make sure that you are successfully  opening capture by `if (!capture)
{
    // failed, to open
}`

Comment: That is already the 3rd command in my code. Do you mean elsewhere?

Comment: Just put video in to your project directory and directly give file name instead of argv

Comment: The goal of your program seems to be to convert one video file into a new video file with MPG codec. You might want to take a look at http://ffmpeg.org, which is much more appropriate for that.